# Self join a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to join a table to itself to get all session_ids, from clientids that had a goal_completion at some (later) point.

Table:

```html
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>clientid</th><th>sessionid</th><th>goalcompletion</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>b</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>c</td><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>x</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>y</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>z</td><td>0</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Expected Output:

```html
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>clientid</th><th>sessionid</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>a</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>b</td></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>c</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I tried a couple of versions, but I can't seem to figure out how this works. This is my latest iteration:

```
SELECT a.clientid,
       a.session_id,
       a.goal1completions_funnel,
       a.goal2completions_funnel,
       a.goal3completions_funnel
FROM _demo.ga_conversions_test a
left JOIN _demo.ga_conversions_test b
  ON a.session_id = b.session_id
  AND (b.goal3completions_funnel = 1
     OR b.goal1completions_funnel = 1
     OR b.goal2completions_funnel = 1)
```

Can you lead me the right way please?

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: Some later point implies a time column of some sort.

Comment: @DavidBrossard Standard-SQL

Comment: @Andii Can you provide a link to Standard SQL? I've never heard of that RDBMS.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Standard SQL is used by Google BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/

Comment: Point of clarification, Google’s Standard SQL is really ANSI SQL. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need to use a join for this task. Please try:

```
select session_id
from _demo.ga_conversions_test 
where goal1completions_funnel=1 OR goal2completions_funnel=1 OR goal3completions_funnel=1
group by session_id
```

EDIT: Based on the provided data, if I were you, I would find the clientids having more than two type of goalcompletion number and use an inner join like below:

```
with cte as (
   select clientid, count(distinct goalcompletion) as CountDifferentGoalCompletion
   from _demo.ga_conversions_test
   group by clientid
   having count(distinct goalcompletion) > 1
)
select a.clientid, a.sessionid
from _demo.ga_conversions_test a
inner join cte on cte.clientid = _demo.ga_conversions_test.clientid
```

EDIT2: If cte structure does not work (will not work if this is not in SQL Server), then:

```
select a.clientid, a.sessionid
from _demo.ga_conversions_test a
inner join (select clientid, count(distinct goalcompletion) as CountDifferentGoalCompletion
            from _demo.ga_conversions_test
            group by clientid
            having count(distinct goalcompletion) > 1) x 
on x.clientid = a.clientid
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realize they question is a bit misleading. I meant all session_ids from client_ids that had one conversion at some point.

Comment: @Andii Could you please add some sample data and expected output to your question?

Comment: I just added an example. Sorry for the inconvienience, it took me some time to figure out how to insert tables since markdown didnt work.

Comment: @Andii could u please try the query below, assuming you are using Sql Server? If you are not using Sql Server and cte structure giving you an error, try using temptable. Or you can also use the query in cte as a subquery like: inner join (...your cte query...) t on t.clientid = maintable.clientid

Comment: thank you so much, the last one looks very promising. Had to change the last line to on x.clientid = a.clientid. I'm now working through the query to try and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the reason you cant get the desired result is that you are joining the tables with the same session_id. Try this:

```
Select ....
From _demo.ga_conversions_test a
left join _demo.ga_conversions_test a on a.session_id < b.session_id (and other criteria)
```

See if it works. If not, postin a sample of your data structure would help us better understand. If gave you a solution, please mark my answer as accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select ct.*
from _demo.ga_conversions_test ct
where exists (select 1
              from _demo.ga_conversions_test ct2
              where ct2.session_id = ct.session_id and
                    1 in (goal1completions_funnel, goal2completions_funnel, goal3completions_funnel) and
                    ct2.<timecol> > ct.<ctimecol>
             );
```